# Is it possible to crack the trifid cipher without the keyword?

Tags: cryptanalysis, classical-cipher

I was learning about the classical ciphers and was looking up the methods to break them without the keywords and when I searched up "cryptanalysis of the trifid cipher" I couldn't find anything. I would be greatful for any help.(Find the outline of what the trifid cipher is [here](http://practicalcryptography.com/ciphers/trifid-cipher/) if you are unaware what it is)

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - I notice in the link you shared that there is a section labeled "cryptanalysis" that says "A good description of cracking the trifid cipher is provided in lecture 17 of the LANIKI Crypto Course Lessons". Did you notice/investigate this link?

Comment: No I didn't notice that. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: Does that link help answer your question? If it does then you're welcome to post an answer to your own question. If not then you can edit your question to include any specific questions you might have about the analysis techniques presented there.

Comment: I am unable to access the link as my devices return the message that they either couldn't find the page or that my search timed out.

Comment: Ah I see, fortunately it looks like you can still [grab the content from the internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150318101446/http://www.und.nodak.edu/org/crypto/crypto/lanaki.crypt.class/lessons/lesson17.zip)

Comment: My machine doesn't want to open the file as apparently 'asc is not a supported file type'

Comment: Try opening it as a text file (it will work) until you identified a proper tool.

Comment: I am unable to do this as at the start I have tried to open this as an adobe acrobat reader DC and every time I download it now it automatically saves as an adobe file.

Comment: You can find Lanaki's lessons at the following link [https://www.cryptogram.org/downloads/LANAKI%20Crypto%20Lessons/LESSON17.pdf](https://www.cryptogram.org/downloads/LANAKI%20Crypto%20Lessons/LESSON17.pdf)